# How can I expand / collapse a Jarvis Widget programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget

I'm working with [JarvisWidgets](http://data.edwardsaquifer.org/widgets.php) and [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) since some time and I need to **open programmatically a widget** that is **collapsed by default**.
Up to now I've tried the following attempts without success.

---

**1st** attempt:

```
$('#my-widget-id').removeClass("jarviswidget-collapsed");
```

---

**2nd** attempt:

```
$('#my-widget-id').removeAttr("data-widget-collapsed");
```

however I'm still unable to trigger the widget expansion.

---

**Note**: the **first method** should be the right one as I've seen that, when the widget is expanded by clicking on the collapse toggle button, the class *jarviswidget-collapsed* is removed while the attribute *data-widget-collapsed="true"* is always there. So the attribute is just used to define the default widget startup state; in other words if the attribute *data-widget-collapsed="true"* is present then the widget will appear collapsed by default, if the attribute is removed the widget will appear expanded by default. Having said that I cannot understand the reason why removing the class *jarviswidget-collapsed*, hence behaving as the widget was expanded by user click, the widget doesn't expand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think maybe they are using something similar to this:

show widget:

```
$('#wid-id-2').removeClass('jarviswidget-collapsed').children('div').slideDown('fast');
```

Hide widget:

```
$('#wid-id-2').addClass('jarviswidget-collapsed').children('div').slideUp('fast');
```

I cannot find the code source of jarvis widgets, but there is an old version [here](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/85620015/) has almost the same code as above but without slideUp or slideDown function, they use only show() and hide() methods

Hope this helps

Comment: YouneL thanks! Works like charm! 
Hence, as far as I understood, the problem was that after removing class we have to "manually open" the widget using slideDown (or SlideUp to collapse). I've seen that many many people was looking for this, the issue is not documented at all. Hope this will help them as well.